# Use proxy or not for getting the fastest speed for our users in the US

Tags: proxy

We have application hosted in the UK and we also have a lot of users in the US.
We can't duplicate our servers to the US (big database with hard replication) but I like to know what do you think about this solution:
The users from the US get to a proxy server we host in the US and he in the background will talk with our servers in UK.

Do I get an high speed from this move or I will only make another action to the user?
If I will not get a slower speed from this move I think it's will be great that users from the US will see US IP address, what do you think about that?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If the US proxy acts as a reverse proxy (cache some of the information), your users will definitely benefit from it.

Comment: And if i don't have a lot to cache does it can make it slower?

Answer (score 0):

If that proxy can make heavy use of caching (i.e. not overseas network access necessary) a proxy will indeed improve loading times.

Comment: And if i don't have a lot to cache does it can make it slower?

Comment: Of course. Then it's user=>proxy=>uk-server instead of user=>uk-server

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are welcome to read another question I publish on the same area:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353083/slow-sql-connection-over-sea